# Understanding Indexing in R

Tags: r

I am just learning R, and trying to play around with indexing to help me understand.  But, I try this code, and don't get what I expect:

```
> x 
[1] 3  6  1 NA  2
> x[!is.na(x[x>2])]
[1]  3  6 NA  2
```

Shouldn't the results of the second command be those elements of `x` that are not `NA` and are `GT 2`?  In other words, it should return `3  6`.  What am I not understanding about this?

Comment: `x[!is.na(x) & x > 2]`

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want:

```
x[!is.na(x) & x > 2]
```

Your command

```
x[!is.na(x[x>2])]
```

first returns all the `x[x>2]`, which is

```
3  6 NA
!is.na(c(3,  6, NA)) 
TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So `x[!is.na(x[x>2])]` has the effect of dropping the third element of x.

Answer (score 1):

As

```
> !is.na(x[x>2])
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

While the length of your vector is 5 Therefore it will give

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Thus, `x[c(1,2,4,5)]` are returns

My approach will be

```
>x <- x[!is.na(s)]
>x[x>2]
[1] 3 6
```

I am still thinking whether one line code is able to do the task.

Okay @6pool have provide a better answer

```
x[!is.na(x) & x > 2]
```